# What is the most performant way to check existance of a number in a set of numbers in python

Tags: python, performance, list, set

So I have a list of numbers in python in a list like this : 
`[1,89,1221,1919,1920,10210,...]` with some thousands of numbers and i want to check if a variabele i is in it.

I do it this way :

```
if i in mylist:
```

But is that the fastest way?

Some further specs :

- the list holds no duplicates
- the list only holds integers
- the list can be ordered if that increases performance
- the list can in fact be a set (so no duplicates)
- the list can be any kind of collection

Comment: Is the size of the set/list of numbers fixed?

Comment: No, it may vary, althoug insights for a fixed number list are welcome too.

Comment: Converting to a set is a relatively expensive operation, but `i in mylist` is expensive too. If you are doing this for more than a few times on the same list it will be  better to use a set

Comment: Did you try `x in some_set` and `x in some_list` using `timeit` yet?  After measuring with `timeit`, what did you learn?  Can you please post the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting to a set and doing `in` is the fastest way.

```
if i in set(mylist):
```

A set is basically a hash table, and lookups are O(1).

Comment: Thanks, If no one argues with this being the fastes way, I accept it later

Comment: No. If he converts the list to a set only at the `if` statement, it would actually be slower than the original code, since this has to traverse the list AND create a new data structure.

Comment: Note that that method is only faster if the operation is to be performed repeatedly. Otherwise the overhead of converting the list to a set will be larger than the performance gained from doing the search in O(1) instead of O(N).

Comment: Thanks Björn, but indeed, it's about lots of repetitions, and I can change my list to a set to begin with

Comment: @Peter: Please *edit your question* to say that you want to repeatedly check whether a single value exists in a large collection, which may be prepared initially.

Answer (score 4):

The conversion to `set` is going to be worthwhile only when you have multiple lookups to do on this list. If performance is important, you should measure if working with a `set` from the start (while still inserting elements) gives a better performance than say a list. In short, try a few things and measure.

However, converting to a set just for a single membership test does sound inefficient if only due to the overhead of creating a new data structure.

```
import random
import timeit

mylist = list(random.randint(1, 50000) for i in xrange(1000))
myset = set(mylist)

s = "1919 in mylist"
t = timeit.Timer(s, "from __main__ import mylist")
print s + ":%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t.timeit(number = 100000)/100000)

s = "1919 in set(mylist)"
t = timeit.Timer(s, "from __main__ import mylist")
print s + ":%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t.timeit(number = 100000)/100000)
```

Here are the results:

```
1919 in mylist:22.81 usec/pass
1919 in set(mylist):65.42 usec/pass
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to use the [timeit module](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) to test various approaches. For example, I whipped up the following code:

```
import array
import bisect
import random
import timeit

mylist = list(random.randint(1, 50000) for i in xrange(1000))
myset = set(mylist)
myarray = array.array('l', mylist)

s = "1919 in mylist"
t = timeit.Timer(s, "from __main__ import mylist")
print s + ":%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t.timeit(number = 100000)/100000)

s = "1919 in myset"
t = timeit.Timer(s, "from __main__ import myset")
print s + ":%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t.timeit(number = 100000)/100000)

s = "1919 in myarray"
t = timeit.Timer(s, "from __main__ import myarray")
print s + ":%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t.timeit(number = 100000)/100000)

mysortedlist = sorted(mylist)
mysortedarray = array.array('l', mysortedlist)

s = "1919 in mysortedlist"
t = timeit.Timer(s, "from __main__ import mysortedlist")
print s + ":%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t.timeit(number = 100000)/100000)

s = "1919 in mysortedarray"
t = timeit.Timer(s, "from __main__ import mysortedarray")
print s + ":%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t.timeit(number = 100000)/100000)

def bisect_in(a, x):
    i = bisect.bisect_left(a, x)
    return (i != len(a) and a[i] == x)

s = "bisect_in(mysortedlist, 1919)"
t = timeit.Timer(s, "from __main__ import bisect_in, mysortedlist")
print s + ":%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t.timeit(number = 100000)/100000)
```

and I got the following results:

```
1919 in mylist:73.89 usec/pass
1919 in myset:0.29 usec/pass
1919 in myarray:103.77 usec/pass
1919 in mysortedlist:75.12 usec/pass
1919 in mysortedarray:114.21 usec/pass
bisect_in(mysortedlist, 1919):4.17 usec/pass
```

which supports the contentions of others that using a set is fastest (under the assumptions that this test code makes).

Answer (score 1):

Make a set from the list, intersect the sets and check the size of the intersection?

Comment: +1: I like your idea, the '?' though does not make it a candidate for accepted answer. (also : i cannot imagine it to be the fastes way)

Comment: I misread your initial question I think - you want to check a single number exists, rather than a set of numbers, in which case you may as well just use `(i in mylist)`, which in O(n) if you are creating the collection, create a set directly, in which case `in` would be O(1)

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to sacrifice some memory efficiency you can build a lookup table in which the list index is the value you wish to check for.

Original list:

```
   In [106]: %timeit i in myList
   10000 loops, best of 3: 21.3 us per loop
```

Building a lookup table:

```
   In [90]: lookup = [False for i in range( max(myList)+1 )]

   In [91]: for i in myList:
                lookup[i] = True

   In [92]: %timeit lookup[i]
   10000000 loops, best of 3: 50.7 ns per loop
```

The lookup table is here ~400x faster than the unsorted list.

This option is only really feasible if the maximum value of your list is acceptably low and if the time to set up the lookup table is significantly less than the over all time spent on checking if variables are in the table.

Interestingly, the lookup table method is 25% slower when using Numpy arrays. (However building the lookup table is much faster)

Edit: This method also outperforms "i in set(myList)" by a factor of 2 for speed.

Comment: Are you sure that merely sorting the list results in an improvement? I tried searching for a non-existent element in both an unsorted and a sorted list and it took roughly the same amount of time for each. Searching for an extant value took more or less time in the sorted list depending up where in the original list the value was.

Comment: You are correct. This is a mistake, the sorting will slow the process down as often as it speed the process up. All the more reason to use sets or lookup tables. I've changed the post so as not to mislead.